Metrics page may appear blank after a few seconds
The metrics page may appear blank after a few seconds.
Then Prometheus shows the job is up, but metrics are not scraped.
My config is
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService("backend"))
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder
    .AddMeter(FormStepHandlerMeter.name)
                    .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting")
                    .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections")
                    .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing")
                    .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics")
                    .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting")
                    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                    .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                    .AddPrometheusExporter()
                )

I use dotnet 6 and this packages:
    OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console 1.9.0
    OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore 1.9.0-beta.1
    OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting 1.9.0
    OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore 1.9.0
    OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.EntityFrameworkCore 1.0.0-beta.12
    OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http 1.9.0
    OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Runtime 1.9.0
    OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.SqlClient 1.9.0-beta.1

Even though nothing is being collected, it takes 259.968 to complete(last scraping).
